# Equation of the sphere centered at $(a,b,c)$ that passes through the origin

Tags: calculus

The question is: Let $(a,b,c)$ denote a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is not in the origin). Find the equation of the sphere which is centered at $(a,b,c)$ that passes through the origin.

I know that the equation of a sphere with $(a,b,c)$ at the center is
 $$(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 + (z-c)^2 = R^2.$$

I'm not really sure how to approach the question. A point in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ to satisfy the equation of the sphere. Let $x=y=z=0$ and you will get an identity for $R^{2}$.

Comment: what do you mean by an identity? is it just the formula for $R^2$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: and is that formula the equation that is centered at (a,b,c) which passes through the origin?

Comment: The formula gives $R^{2}$ in terms of $a, b$ and $c$, which is the answer you are looking for. Other people have written down the answer, so I'll just come out and say it: your equation is $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$

Comment: ahh I see it now, I was getting a,b,c confused with x,y,z. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the value of $R$ using $R^2$$=$$a^2$$+b^2$$+c^2$ since as the sphere passes through the origin the radius of the sphere should be equal to the distance between the origin and the point $(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what $R$ means in the context of your equation for the sphere above - hint - it also begins with the letter r. What should that be for your sphere?

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a,b,c)=p$. The desired equation is then $\|x-p\|^2=\|p\|^2$,